Using Power Query in Excel to pull Sharepoint Documents Library - how to view managed metadata?
I can access a Sharepoint Document Library using Power Query in Excel but some of the data coming in from the Document Library display as [Record] in the results. I am assuming this is because those columns in the Library are of managed metadata types. (Kind of like a drop down list to let users select pre defined values).
PQ data
In the PQ editor, if I click on any of the cells with [Record] in it I get another view displayed that does not show any useful data, a couple of fields I don't know what they are for and one unique ID field.
Record data view
I want those cells to display the same value as they are displaying in Sharepoint. I would think there is a way to do this via the query being used but am not sure how to write it. I'm not new to programming but am new to Power Query. The current query is below.
Table.SelectRows(#"Navigation 1", each [Capability Area] <> null)

Capability Area is the name of one of the columns in Sharepoint that has managed metadata, the other is Capability. As you can see in the query above it is, with the each command, iterating through each row to determine if it should be displayed or not (if it is not null). I would like to append to this query so that it would also, for each row, display the record value and not [Record].

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I rewrote the question.

In the power query editor it would be transform > expand (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/work-with-a-list-record-or-table-structured-column-power-query-d5e552be-c143-4f06-9a5e-0960bbaaf480)

Managed metadata is hard to work with. In SharePoint, the GUID will be used to look up the term text value at run time and display it.
If you want to connect that to a PQ, you may need to download the managed metadata column into a CSV or an Excel file and add that to the query. Then you can merge the queries.
